# RSpec - stub #super call in a Module#prepend monkeypatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am converting monkeypatches which use `alias_method_chain` to `Module#prepend`. (Mostly because `active_support` v5.0 deprecates `alias_method_chain`.) But doing so makes `rspec` tests harder.

My old `alias_method_chain` code looks like:

```
class Client
  def call_with_reconnect
    begin
      call_without_reconnect
    rescue => ex
      reconnect
      call_without_reconnect
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :call, :reconnect
end
```

I can test this with `rspec` like:

```
it "should silently reconnect when the original request expires" do
  allow(subject).to receive(:call_without_reconnect).and_raise(TimeoutError)
  expect{ subject.call }.to_not raise_error(TimeoutError)
end
```

My new `Module#prepend` code looks like:

```
class Client
  module MethodOverrides
    def call
      begin
        super
      rescue => ex
        reconnect
        super
      end
    end
  end
  prepend MethodOverrides
end
```

This code works, but I don't know how to test it. I want to force a timeout error when the old method is called, but I can't stub the `super` call. And I can't stub the call to `call`, because that's also the name of my monkeypatch method.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around with your code, I rewrote the `call` method on `Client` after the override and it overrode the original `Client#call` which should help in stubbing the method to raise a `TimeoutError`.

Given:

```
class Client
  def call
    puts "super"
  end

  module MethodOverrides
    def call
      begin
        puts "override"
        super
      rescue => ex
        puts "reconnect"
        super
      end
    end
  end
  prepend MethodOverrides
end
```

I ran:

```
Client.new.call
# override
# super
# => nil
```

Then I manually monkey patched the `Client#call` method:

```
class Client
  def call
    raise "a timeout happened"
  end
end
```

And I got:

```
Client.new.call
# override
# reconnect
# => RuntimeError: a timeout happened
```

It's not exactly what you had before but with a little restructuring of your specs you can put this approach to use i.e. causing a Timeout and seeing if the `reconnect` method gets called. Or better yet, that `Client#call` has the expected side effects when it is called with and without a Timeout. In other words, test for the correct behavior of the class.